# How to update salary based on the value in a drop down list and user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a list of employees with salary info.. 
on my html page I have a drop down list with their id # and a field to enter the new salary ... When the user clicks submit button I want to update the salary of that employee with the selected id# from the drop down list.. I am trying to do this as part of learning angular js.

Here is my script.js so far:

```
var myApp = angular.module("myModule",[])
.controller("myController", function($scope){
    $scope.message = "Learning Angular JS!";
    var employees = [
        {eid:"1", firstName:"Jack", lastName:"Joba", gender:"Male", salary:"50000"},
        {eid:"2", firstName:"Jim", lastName:"Henry", gender:"Female", salary:"40000"},
        {eid:"3", firstName:"Jacky", lastName:"Mash", gender:"Female", salary:"60000"},
        {eid:"4", firstName:"Rahul", lastName:"Pat", gender:"Female", salary:"70000"}
    ];
    $scope.employees = employees;
    $scope.image = "snoopy1.jpg";

    $scope.y="";
    $scope.x ="";

    $scope.updateLastName = function()    
    {
        y.lastName=x;
    }


});
```

html page:

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.1/angular.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>



<title>Hello</title>

</head>


<body ng-app="myModule" ng-controller="myController">


<div>{{message}}</div>
<br><br>
<select>
  <option ng-repeat="employee in employees">{{employee.eid}}</option>
</select>
<input id="inp1" placeholder="enter new salary"></input><button ng-click="updateLastName()">Submit</button>
<br><br>
<table border="2px">
<thead>

    <tr><th>First Name</th><th>Last Name</th><th>Gender</th><th>Salary</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
<td>{{employee.firstName}}</td>
<td>{{employee.lastName}}</td>
<td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
<td>{{employee.salary}}</td>

</tr>

</tbody>
</table>


<br>

<br>

<img ng-src="{{image}}" style="height: 100px;width: 100px;">


<script>

</script>


</body>
</html>
```

How can I achieve this?..  I am not sure how I can pass in the selected options id and the new salary entered to the update function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a model to `<input ng-model="newSalary" id="inp1" placeholder="enter new salary"></input>`

Save your selected employee `<select ng-model="selectedEmployee">
  <option ng-repeat="employee in employees">{{employee.eid}}</option>
</select>`

You can pass the employee to the update function and the new salary `<button ng-click="updateLastName(selectedEmployee, newSalary)">Submit</button>`

And in your controller update the employee like:

```
$scope.updateLastName = function(selectedEmployee, newSalary)    
{
        for(var i = 0 ; i < $scope.employees.length; i++){
        if($scope.employees[i].eid == selectedEmployee){
        $scope.employees[i].salary = newSalary;
        break;
      }
    }
}
```

Edit: I've missread the question sorry. Updated the answer

Comment: I am not sure if its working or not. .After update I was expecting to see the new salary in the table.. but its not updating.. it should right?..

Comment: The selected employee was and id, so it is necessary to find that employee and update it. I've made a fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/qwkbyuyk/

Comment: Makes sense now. Thanks so much!